# Run SSIS Package as different user

Tags: ssis

I have been googling for ages and messing around with the package properties but I can't seem to be able to get my package to run as a different user than my current windows login from within Visual Studio.

In particular I want a connection manager to run as a different windows account and not a SQL account.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: You need a Proxy account, then run the job using that proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Amusingly enough, you have the answer in your question, specifically, `run as`. [RunAs](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true) and in case MS butchers links again, [RunAs](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

RunAs allows you to run a program as another user. You can't automate the entry of credentials, which is a pain and you won't be able to see your password but it does work. It also fails in situations like SSRS development when you attempt to preview a report, that is spawned in a separate process which does not inherit the credentials. But, I had no issues with it from an SSIS perspective.

```
runas /netonly /user:OtherDomain\billinkc "devenv.exe /nosplash"
```

where "devenv.exe" is the full qualified path to your Visual Studio version and whether you have a 64 bit OS. On my machine, that could be

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: until you find that this is blocked by policy and won't work

Answer (score -2):

You can use Configuration files in SSIS.  You have to enable your package to use them and then edit the .config file to override the package connection properties with the properties (username/password/Server/etc.) you want it to use.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that they are using SQL Server Authentication when they specifically mentioned "run as a different windows account and not a SQL account."

Comment: Correct, you cannot use config files in this manner